# sklearn pipeline with PCA on feature subset using FunctionTransformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

Consider the task of chaining a PCA and regression, where PCA performs dimensionality reduction and regression does the prediction.

Example taken from the sklearn documentation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import linear_model, decomposition, datasets
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

logistic = linear_model.LogisticRegression()

pca = decomposition.PCA()
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('pca', pca), ('logistic', logistic)])

digits = datasets.load_digits()
X_digits = digits.data
y_digits = digits.target

n_components = [5, 10]
Cs = np.logspace(-4, 4, 3)

param_grid = dict(pca__n_components=n_components, logistic__C=Cs)
estimator = GridSearchCV(pipe,param_grid)
estimator.fit(X_digits, y_digits)
```

How can I perform dimensionality reduction only on a subset of my feature set using [FunctionTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html) (for example, restrict PCA to the last ten columns of X_digits)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a function (called `last_ten_columns` below) that returns the last 10 columns of the input `X_digits`.  Create the function transformer that points to the function, and use it as the first step of the pipeline.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import linear_model, decomposition, datasets
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

logistic = linear_model.LogisticRegression()

pca = decomposition.PCA()

def last_ten_columns(X):
    return X[:, -10:]

func_trans = FunctionTransformer(last_ten_columns)

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('func_trans',func_trans), ('pca', pca), ('logistic', logistic)])

digits = datasets.load_digits()
X_digits = digits.data
y_digits = digits.target

n_components = [5, 10]
Cs = np.logspace(-4, 4, 3)

param_grid = dict(pca__n_components=n_components, logistic__C=Cs)
estimator = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid)
estimator.fit(X_digits, y_digits)
```

Comment: This selects features also for logistic regression. Is this desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer selects features also for logistic regression. If this is not the desired behavior, you can use ColumnTransfor.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html

```
pca_transformer = ColumnTransformer([('pca', PCA(), [-10:])], remainder="passthrough")
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('pca_transformer', pca_transformer), ('logistic', logistic)])
```